# Owin/Katana - Integration with ASP.NET Request Lifecycle

Tags: asp.net, owin, katana

Owin/Katana could be hosted either with IIS or self hosting. When hosting over IIS, what happens to the ASP.NET Request Life cycle? Will it still run as before? (BeginRequest, etc ...). What basically happens?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's the same and the OWIN/Katana middleware can be interleaved at the same stanges in IIS as needed. Check the UseStageMarker API to let IIS know when you want the middleware to run:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.extensions.integratedpipelineextensions.usestagemarker%28v=vs.111%29.aspx

Also, this goes into some details as well:

http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-middleware-in-the-iis-integrated-pipeline

Comment: Hi Brock, thanks for the answer. After asking my question here, I had already found the second link above you sent me. Regards